# Hiding list items on clear input

Tags: javascript, list

been looking for an answer to my question but couldnt find anything particular, so will ask here. The problem that I have is that when I clear my input field, all the list items that I have show up on the screen, and they shouldn't be visible, since they are set to display: none, until there's an letter inputted in the search field. Here's my JS code, and will provide a link to glitch so you can see the project if you need. I am new to javascript, so if its a stupid question, dont be harsh at me :D Thanks in advance!

```
   //Get the input element
let filterInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");

//Add event listener
filterInput.addEventListener("keyup", filterNames);

function filterNames(){
    //Get the value of the input
    let filterValue = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toUpperCase();

    //Get the names unordered list
    let ul = document.getElementById("names");

    //Get the list items
    let li = ul.querySelectorAll("li.collection-item");
    let h = ul.querySelectorAll("li.collection-header");

    //Loop trough the collection
    for(let i=0; i < li.length; i++){
        let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        //If matched
        if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1 && a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0){
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else{
            li[i].style.display = "";
        }
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < h.length; i++){  
        let title = h[i].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
        if(title.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue[0]) > -1){
            h[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            h[i].style.display = "";
        }
    };
}
```

Here's a link to the glitch project: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/quirky-girdle?path=index.html:10:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `let has_input = filterValue.length > 0;` and then change each `if(...)` to `if (has_input && ...)`.

Also use `style.display = "none";` to hide items.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the work as I meant it. Really thank you, this bothered me much more than it probably should haha, still really new to javascript :D

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because to set a display of none, you don't write

`.style.display = "";`

But instead

`.style.display = "none";`

Comment: Peter B below provided the answer :D By the way, its .style.display = " "; was set in order to them to stay at display: none, because I've set them in the CSS to have a display:none, and then on input to change on display:block :D